# Help me understand the CPT signatures of different physical quantities

Tags: electromagnetism, symmetry, field-theory, invariants, cpt-symmetry

I am an engineer and not a trained physicist, but still I am fascinated by symmetries and I want to understand them.
Specifically, in a paper ¹ I found the below table which covers a large number of physical quantities and their behaviour under **C**, **P** and **T** symmetry. But it is not at all clear to me how to derive this table.

Let's take, for example, the $E$-field, which appears to be a most basic quantity. **Are the following assumptions true and complete?**

- The $E$-field is not **C**-symmetric, because the field direction is reversed if I swap negative and positive charges.
- The $E$-field is not **P**-symmetric, because the field direction is reversed if I swap the *locations* of the sources (charges).
- The $E$-field is **T**-symmetric, because the electric charge fundamentally does not depend on time.

It would be great if anyone could elaborate this kind of stuff to me in more detail. :) Thank you!

(*Question edited to be more specific.*)

[image]

¹ Paolo Lazzeretti, "Static and optical anapole magnetizabilities and polarizabilities", J. Chem. Phys. 153, 074102 (2020) https://doi.org/10.1063/5.0019937

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Community: Done.